# Importing Keras Neural Network to Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I developed a neural network in Keras that forecasts energy consumption. Now, I want to import that neural network to Matlab where I will use the NN forecast to solve a Linear Programming problem.

I saved the neural network in a h5 file.

I tried to use `importKerasNetwork()` from Matlab, but I got the following error:

```
Warning: File 'C:\\Users\\Amin y Lubna\\Desktop\\Escritorio Virtual\\Carrera Amin\\1.TFG\\Informacion\\Modelo1.h5' was
saved in Keras version '2.4.0'. Import of Keras versions newer than '2.2.4' is not supported. The imported model may not
exactly match the model saved in the Keras file. 
Error using assembleNetwork (line 47)
Invalid network.

Error in nnet.internal.cnn.keras.importKerasNetwork (line 35)
Network         = assembleNetwork(LayersOrGraph);

Error in importKerasNetwork (line 91)
Network = nnet.internal.cnn.keras.importKerasNetwork(modelfile, varargin{:});

Caused by:
    Network: Incompatible layer types. The network contains layer types not supported with recurrent layers.
    Detected recurrent layers:
        layer 'lstm' (LSTM)
        layer 'lstm_1' (LSTM)
    Detected incompatible layers:
        layer 'lstm_input' (Image Input)
    Layer 'lstm': Input size mismatch. LSTM layers must have scalar input size, but input size (24×10×1) was received.
    Try using a flatten layer before the LSTM layer.
```

Then I tried to load the model embedding a python script in Matlab.

```
py.keras.models.load_model()
```

But I got the following:

```
Unable to resolve the name py.keras.models.load_model.
```

Is there  a way to troubleshoot the errors I get?

Or there is an easier way to accomplish my purpose?

Comment: As the error clearly says `Import of Keras versions newer than '2.2.4' is not supported. The imported model may not exactly match the model saved in the Keras file`, so did you tried downgrade `keras` version from `2.4.0` to `2.2.3/2.2.4` version? and let us know. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering!!! Eventually, I decided to run the NN in python and then pass the output to the optimizer in Matlab.